What is the new method for the deprecated background & onSurface
import 'package:expensetracker/screens/home/views/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAppView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyAppView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Expense Tracker',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
            background: Colors.grey.shade100,
            onBackground: Colors.black,
            primary: const Color(0xFF00B2E7),
            secondary: const Color(0xFFE064F7),
            tertiary: const Color(0xFFFF8D6C),
            outline: Colors.grey),
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

i just want same result of the problem sadly the background is depracated.

Use surface instead of background in your ThemeData's colorScheme.

background should be replaced with surface and onBackground should be replaced with onSurface.
Read More about the new color scheme migration guide here

In my case, I solved it by using  ThemeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor. This solution was suggested by a user named Troy here:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/149158
Sample usage:
color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor

